# How to change textColor of a button from XML in Android?

Tags: android, button, android-layout, selector

I am using a `selector` to change the background drawable of the button in different states (focused, pressed, normal). Is there any way to change the text color too? I want to provide various text colors for various button states, but I want to do it from the xml. Is this possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes it can be done. You just do the same way you do for the button drawable. Then assign it to `android:textColor="@drawable/yourselector"`

Comment: Thats a nice idea. I'll try that.

Comment: Fantastic! I would have never thought of that!

Comment: for me it's giving android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi/btn_text.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f020001 ..any suggestion ?

Answer (score 11):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:color="#000000" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:color="#000000" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:color="#FFFFFF" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Try combining the above with the `android:drawable` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If it's programmatically, you could use:

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);
button.setTextColor(Color.yourcolor);
```

In xml it'll be the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `android:color="#ff0000"` in selector for `focused` and another color for `default` state.Then in xml of button `android:textColor="@drawable/yourselector"`